# Почему медиа-файл Wordpress создает страницу?

Tags: wordpress

некоторые медия создают свои страницы. Если к примеру они доступы по ссылке https://site.ru/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/ruchka-...

То создают свою страницу с https://site.ru/ruchka-sharikovaya-senator-point-m... Это плохо для индексации. Как можно запретить создания страниц медиафайлам

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Почему медиа-файл Wordpress создает страницу?

Потому что [`attachments` - это тип контента](https://wordpress.org/support/article/post-types/#attachments), почти такой же, как `post` или `page`.

> Это плохо для индексации. Как можно запретить создания страниц
> медиафайлам

Чтобы не создавались страницы вложений - не нужно грузить файлы в медиатеку. Но это чревато другими проблемами. Правильный вопрос должен звучать так: "как избежать индексации ПСами страниц вложений?".
Так вот, кого волнует SEO тот обычно использует SEO-плагины. А в них, кроме других нужных вещей, реализована и возможность включить редирект со страниц вложений на родительский пост.  Или как минимум используют плагин только с этой функцией.
Но ничего не мешает и самостоятельно написать свой велосипед с таким редиректом.